# PHP header not working after uploading it to the server

Tags: php, html, redirect, header

This is the simple code which i uploaded to my web server to find why the header not working in the main application. Even this doesn't work i'm using the i page server. This works fin in the localhost wamp server.

```
<?php 
 ob_start();

 header('Location: login-twitter.com');

 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I also tried the below code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Hello</h1> 
  <?php 
  ob_start();

   header('Location: login-twitter.com');

  ob_end_flush(); 
  ?> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The second won't work Because you've already sent an header (text) to the browser. (i think)

Comment: `ob_start()` has no power upon the content that was already produced. You need to put it at the beginning of the script, before outputting anything either from PHP (with `echo()`, `print()`, `printf()`, `readfile()` etc) or embedded HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the very start of the file, add following lines:

Even before the HTML `<!Doctype>`

```
<?php session_start(); 
ob_start();
?>
```

**Note: Redirection will not occur if you have some HTML output on browser.**

Comment: Not after `doctype`. **Before** it. Before any HTML or whatever content you produce in that page.

Answer (score 2):

try to use header('Location: http://www.login-twitter.com/'); instead of header('Location : login-twitter.com');

Comment: This is the correct usage. The value of `Location:` header must be and absolute URI, i.e. it must start with the protocol. `login-twitter.com` is not an URL, it is just a host name.

Answer (score 1):

You must do the redirect ( header('Location: login-twitter.com'); ) before the html starting tag.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.assign('http://www.login-twitter.com');
</script>
```